# What arguments do Catholics and Orthodox Christians use against Matthew 1:25 disproving the perpetual virginity of Mary?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, virgin-mary, perpetual-virginity

Both Catholics and Orthodox Christians believe that the blessed Virgin Mary remained a virgin not only until she had given birth to the Lord but for her entire life, but most Protestants use Matthew 1:25 as evidence that Mary did have sexual relations with Joseph, but what arguments do Catholics and Orthodox Christians use against Matthew 1:25 disproving the perpetual virginity of Mary?

Matthew 1:25 reads:

> And knew her not till she had brought forth her firstborn son: and he
> called his name Jesus.

I would really like to hear this perspective from Catholic and Orthodox Christians.